# adding a arraylist to a choicebox in my javafx program

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

So I've been trying to transfer my arraylist to a choicebox I've created in my JavaFX class. However I got some problems loading the item names. I've created a seperate class called Item where it contains a constructor I've made and I have created a method that returns the item name. However I want to transfer the item properties to my choicebox but only display the item name.

```
public class Item {


    private final String name, description;
    private boolean spoiled, buyable;
    private final int price, nutrition;
    private final boolean isFood;

    private double hoursToRot = 15;

    public Item() {
        this.name = null;
        this.description = null;
        this.price = 0;
        this.nutrition = 0;
        this.isFood = false;
    }
    public Item(String name, String description, int price, boolean buyable, boolean isFood, int nutrition)
    {

       this.description = description;
       this.name = name;      
       this.price = price;
       this.buyable = buyable;
       this.isFood = isFood;
       this.nutrition = nutrition;

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
...
```

As you can see this is my item class

```
public class Game 
{
    Item item = new Item();
       public ArrayList<Item> supermarkedItems = new ArrayList();     
     public void supermarkedItems() {


        Item meat, milk, cake, rice, ryebread;

        milk = new Item("milk", "This is milk!", 14, true, true, 20);
        meat = new Item("meat", "This is meat!", 35, true, true, 30);
        cake = new Item("cake", "This is a whole cake!", 60, true, true, 50);
        rice = new Item("rice", "This is 500g of white rice!", 25, true, true, 50);
        ryebread = new Item("ryebread", "This is a loaf of ryebread", 25, true, true, 25);

        supermarkedItems.add(meat);
        supermarkedItems.add(milk);
        supermarkedItems.add(cake);
        supermarkedItems.add(rice);
        supermarkedItems.add(ryebread);



     }

     public ArrayList<Item> getsupermarkedList() {
         return supermarkedItems;
     }
     public String getItemNames () {
         return item.getName();
     }
...
```

And this is my Game class.
In my javafx program I've made a singleton class to transfer my stuff to my JavaFX class.

```
public class OrderTableController implements Initializable {

    Game g1 = Game.getInstance();
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Item> cbItems = new ChoiceBox<Item>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(g1.getsupermarkedList())); 
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        cbItems.getItems().addAll(g1.getItemNames());


...
```

However for some reason I really can't transfer my Items to the new observableArrayList I have created in my choicebox class.
[These are the errors i receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKGqM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are attempting to add objects of type `String` to a list that is supposed to contain the type `Item`. You can only add objects that are, or extend, the class `Item`.

To choose the text for an object to display in a `ChoiceBox` you will want to override `toString()` in your class.

You can add this to your Item class to display the name in the ChoiceBox:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

And you would add the items to the ChoiceBox by doing the following:

```
cbItems.getItems().addAll( g1.getsupermarkedList() );
```